# Recompile turtlebot from source problem

Tags: ros, turtlebot, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I need to implement a multi-turtlebot application with Hydro ROS so that I installed the turtlebot from source using the instructions below:

> mkdir ~/turtlebot
> cd ~/turtlebot
> wstool init src https/raw.github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/hydro/turtlebot.rosinstall -j8
> source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
> rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
> catkin_make

I spawned two turtlebots but I have problems with the “odom” topic that doesn’t resolve correctly.  I am getting just one “/odom” topic instead of two like “robot1/odom” and “robot2/odom”

Since I have this problems, incorrect resolution of each robot prefix, I made some changes on the source file gazebo_ros_create.cpp  located at  HOME/turtlebot/src/turtlebot_create_desktop/create_gazebo_plugins/src
Then, I compiled the from ”/turtlebot”  “folder” using “catkin_make”  but I noticed that my changes didn’t take effect.
Am I doing something wrong?  Or Do I need to do something else to see the effect of my changes?

Please any help would be very much appreciated!! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157266/recompile-turtlebot-from-source-problem/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it.First, I run $ catkin_make clean then $ catkin_make  and compiled it

---

Originally posted by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) with karma: 63 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0